# How to use COM to pass a string from c# to c++?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, com, com-interop

when i try to call c# code from c++, i followed instructions from this article

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828736

part of my c# is :

```
[Guid("6A2E9B00-C435-48f8-AEF1-747E9F39E77A")]
public interface IGameHelper
{
 void getInfo(out string result);
}

public class GameHelper : IGameHelper
{
 void getInfo(out string result)
 {
  result =  new StringBuilder().Append("Hello").ToString();
 }

}
```

part of my c++ code:

```
#import "../lst/bin/Release/LST.tlb" named_guids raw_interfaces_only
using namespace LST;
using namespace std;

...
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
IGameHelperPtr pIGame(__uuidof(GameHelper));
BSTR ha = SysAllocString(NULL);
pIGame->GetInfo(&ha);
wprintf(_T(" %s"),ha);
SysFreeString(ha);
```

but I just cannot get the string result value, it works fine when i try to get integer results,but not string.

I dont know COM very much. PLEASE HELP ME.
Thank you.

Comment: wprintf(_T(" %s"),ha);
always prints <null> and it seems BSTR ha can not get the result string.

Comment: BSTR ha = SysAllocString(NULL) - is not need here, because result is OUT parameter. Instead use BSTR ha = NULL;

Comment: Between C++ and C#, it may be simpler to use C++/CLI for interop. Then you can avoid COM, which is always a good thing. :)

Comment: @jalf thanks for the comment. CLI is a simpler solution, but i really want to find out the right COM way.

Comment: can you change method signature from 'out string' to 'ref string'?

Comment: @Arseny: I'd rather suggest to change it to `string getInfo()`.

Comment: @sharptooth @Arseny @jalf @Victor, sorry for my poor english. i tried string getInfo() ,in c++, it get the same tlh file, the getInfo's signature in c++ is also "void getInfo(BSTR *result)". I first use string result, and then ref string result , and then out string result.but it just doesnot work.

Comment: What happens if you stick to `string getInfo()`?

Comment: @sharptooth I tried 'string getInfo()' again , and it prints <null>.

Comment: Do you return the right string from `string getInfo()`?

Comment: @sharptooth in c# i just return new StringBuilder().Append("hello").ToString() and in c++ i used the same code showed in the post.  and it prints <null>.

Answer (score 0):

[According to Msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms221458.aspx) if you call SysAllocString whilst passing in NULL, it returns NULL.

Aren't you therefore passing a reference to a NULL pointer into your COM interface? And if so ha will never get populated? (I'm not sure with COM so may be wrong)

Comment: Yes Sysallocstring(NULL) will return NULL. but i am toled that COM server should allocate the string and the com client should free the result using sysfreestring. I tried BSTR ha = SysAllocString(L"NotJarvis");pIGame->GetInfo(&ha);
wprintf(_T(" %s"),ha); but it prints NotJarvis too.

Comment: Yeah sorry - it's been a while since I've used COM - you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Generally your code should work but first make sure it compiles correctly as `void getInfo(out string result)` inside of `GameHelper` should be public. Then again `pIGame->GetInfo(&ha);` should be fixed with `getInfo`. So you may be running an older version of the code.

Comment: thanks for your time. sorry for the spelling mistakes. I've already used "gacutil /u XXX" and then "gacutil /i XXX.dll" to refresh my com in gac. and clean and rebuild the c++ project,but it just can not work. it's very strange.

Comment: Maybe you should also check HRESULT returned by the call to getInfo. The code should work, I tested it myself.

Answer (score 0):

Change your C# code to:

```
[Guid("6A2E9B00-C435-48f8-AEF1-747E9F39E77A")]
public interface IGameHelper
{
    string getInfo();
}


public class GameHelper : IGameHelper
{
    public string getInfo()
    {
       return "Hello World";
    }

}
```

Then your C++ client to:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
IGameHelperPtr pIGame(__uuidof(GameHelper));
_bstr_t ha = pIGame->GetInfo();
wprintf(_T(" %s"),ha);
```

That should work