# Add reference to VS 6.0 C++ help!

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio, com, vb6

I am a CS student who is in an intern. My supervisor is really busy and he said I could use this site if I have questions.

I need to modify a VS6.0 C++ program. I have made a C# class library that is COMVisible.
In Visual Basic 6.0 it recongnizes the type library and works how it is supposed to. I made a Visual Basic 6.0 to test the type library, but now I need to implement my class library into the VS6.0 C++ program.

I need help on with the following:
How to add a type library (tlb) or dll reference or reference like method to VS6.0C++ (I just can't find an article on how to add it)
The tlb was easy to add in Visual Basic 6.0

Translate a simple code to C++ that uses my COMVisible library.

Have a local variable:

```
Public ls As New pcbCOMVisibleLibrary
```

Also have this in a method:

```
Dim work As Boolean
work = ls.Post(Text1.Text, Text2.Text)
Label1.Caption = work
```

Comment: You really need to upgrade your version of Visual Studio. 6.0 is notorious for being buggy.

Comment: There is no direct equivalent.  You start by #import-ing the DLL into your VC++ project, which generates a number of files and wrapper classes (tli and tlh files), which you can then leverage to call into the DLL.  But it is nowhere near as simple as it is in VB and .NET.

Comment: This snippet will give you some clues how to interact with a COM object from C++ via a tlb lib: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262326/how-to-use-com-to-pass-a-string-from-c-to-c/6278267#6278267

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find several ways to do just that: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/loadingdll.aspx. I know that just posting a link is not very nice, but in this case the article on codeproject explains what you want to do very well and there's little more to say.

I think your problem falls into the Case1 of this article.